# .Net Removing all the first 0 of a string

Tags: c#, regex, .net-3.5

I got the following :

01.05.03

I need to convert that to 1.5.3

The problem is I cannot only trim the 0 because if I got :

01.05.10

I need to convert that to 1.5.10

So, what's the better way to solve that problem ? Regex ? If so, any regex example doing that ?

Comment: Are you trying to format a date? There are better ways to do this than regex.

Comment: No it's not a date, it's a hierarchy level

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Expanding on the answer of @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner:

```
string Strip0s(string s)
{
    return string.Join<int>(".", from x in s.Split('.') select int.Parse(x));
}
```

Comment: +1 for Linq-ifying it! I keep forgetting that it's possible to do things like that.

Comment: +1 nice alternative, though it does not deal with the `"00.03.03"` case (which may or may not occur).

Answer (score 15):

Regex-replace

```
(?<=^|\.)0+
```

with the empty string. The regex is:

```
(?<=     # begin positive look-behind (i.e. "a position preceded by")
  ^|\.   #   the start of the string or a literal dot †
)        # end positive look-behind
0+       # one or more "0" characters
```

*† note that not all regex flavors support variable-length look-behind, but .NET does.*

If you expect this kind of input: `"00.03.03"` and want to to keep the leading zero in this case (like `"0.3.3"`), use this expression instead:

```
(?<=^|\.)0+(?=\d)
```

and again replace with the empty string.

---

From the comments (thanks Kobi): There is a more concise expression that does not require look-behind and is equivalent to my second suggestion:

```
\b0+(?=\d)
```

which is

```
\b       # a word boundary (a position between a word char and a non-word char) 
0+       # one or more "0" characters
(?=\d)   # positive look-ahead: a position that's followed by a digit
```

This works because the `0` happens to be a word character, so word boundaries can be used to find the first `0` in a row. It is a more compatible expression, because many regex flavors do not support variable-length look-behind, and some (like JavaScript) no look-behind at all.

Comment: Can you give me an example of the c# code that does that with the replace please ?

Comment: @Melursus: No, because this is *really easy* to find. The official documentation and uncounted websites (including Stack Overflow itself) can give you an example how to use regular expressions in .NET.

Comment: `\b0+(?=\d)` will also work nicely here, and keep a single zero.

Comment: @Kobi: Nice catch, this is even better than my look-behind.

Answer (score 3):

You could [split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx) the string on `.`, then trim the leading `0`s on the results of the split, then merge them back together.

I don't know of a way to do this in a single operation, but you could write a function that hides this and makes it *look* like a single operation. ;)

**UPDATE:**

I didn't even think of the other guy's regex. Yeah, that will probably do it in a single operation.

Comment: +1 for ease of read of resulting code, rather than a regex that would require comments

Comment: @Miki Watts: Well, the regex solution requires no other comment than the split/loop/join variant: `/* remove leading zeros on build number */`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way you could do what FrustratedWithFormsDesigner suggests:

```
string s = "01.05.10";
string s2 = string.Join(
    ".",
    s.Split('.')
        .Select(str => str.TrimStart('0'))
        .ToArray()
);
```

This is *almost* the same as dtb's answer, but doesn't require that the substrings be valid integers (it would also work with, e.g., "000A.007.0HHIMARK").

**UPDATE**: If you'd want any strings consisting of all 0s in the input string to be output as a single 0, you could use this:

```
string s2 = string.Join(
    ".",
    s.Split('.')
        .Select(str => TrimLeadingZeros(str))
        .ToArray()
);

public static string TrimLeadingZeros(string text) {
    int number;
    if (int.TryParse(text, out number))
        return number.ToString();
    else
        return text.TrimStart('0');
}
```

Example input/output:

```
00.00.000A.007.0HHIMARK // input
0.0.A.7.HHIMARK         // output
```

Comment: That's the solution I had before I changed it to `int.Parse`. It fails when a part is made up entirely of `'0'` characters, e.g., `"03.00.10"`.

Comment: @dtb: What do you mean by "fails"? I don't see where the OP specified what should happen in this case. If trailing zeros are to be removed, I would've thought the output of "03.00.10" should be "03..10", which it is. Otherwise, the OP would need to provide slightly more detailed requirements (unless I'm missing something).

Answer (score 1):

There's also the old-school way which probably has better performance characteristics than most other solutions mentioned. Something like:

```
static public string NormalizeVersionString(string versionString)
{
    if(versionString == null)
       throw new NullArgumentException("versionString");

    bool insideNumber = false;    
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(versionString.Length);
    foreach(char c in versionString)
    {
        if(c == '.')
        {
            sb.Append('.');
            insideNumber = false;
        }
        else if(c >= '1' && c <= '9')
        {
            sb.Append(c);
            insideNumber = true;
        }
        else if(c == '0')
        {
            if(insideNumber)
                sb.Append('0');
        }
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string s = "01.05.10";
string newS = s.Replace(".0", ".");
newS = newS.StartsWith("0") ? newS.Substring(1, newS.Length - 1) : newS;

Console.WriteLine(newS);
```

NOTE: You will have to thoroughly check for possible input combination.

Comment: This might not work if he had `001.00005.10`, but he didn't specify if that would be possible.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like it is a date format, if so I would use Date processing code

```
DateTime time = DateTime.Parse("01.02.03");
String newFormat = time.ToString("d.M.yy");
```

or even better

```
String newFormat = time.ToShortDateString();
```

which will respect you and your clients culture setting.

If this data is not a date then don't use this :)

Comment: sorry missed the comment. by OP

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar requirement to parse a string with street adresses, where some of the house numbers had leading zeroes and I needed to remove them while keeping the rest of the text intact, so I slightly edited the accepted answer to meet my requirements, maybe someone finds it useful. Basically doing the same as accepted answer, with the difference that I am checking if the string part can be parsed as an integer, and defaulting to the string value when false;

```
string Strip0s(string s)
{
    int outputValue;
    return
        string.Join(" ",
            from x in s.Split(new[] { ' ' })
            select int.TryParse(x, out outputValue) ? outputValue.ToString() : x);
}
```

> Input: "Islands Brygge 34 B 07 TV"
>
> Output: "Islands Brygge 34 B 7 TV"